# s3fs permissions for s3 directory

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

I'm trying to mount the s3 directory to my EC2 instance. I'm getting everything to work except my user is not able to write to the mounted directory. I even ran with the `allow_other` permission set. Is there something else?

1. I created the directory and made sure the permission was there for my current user
2. I then mounted the s3 bucket using the `allow_other` option
3. My user is able to read but not write...

Is there something else I need to do? I read the following sites for this:

https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=185

http://xentek.net/articles/448/installing-fuse-s3fs-and-sshfs-on-ubuntu/

http://michaelaldridge.info/post/12086788604/mounting-s3-within-an-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly have no clue what happened. But I restarted my EC2 instance and ran the above again and it worked perfectly.